# Number of distinct necklaces using K colors

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I have a task to find the number of distinct necklaces using K colors in C++.

> Two necklaces are considered to be distinct if one of the necklaces
>   cannot be obtained from the second necklace by rotating the second
>   necklace by any angle .
>   Find the total number of distinct necklaces modulo (10^9+7).

I think this formula is good to solve a problem:

[image]

And I implemented a program using C++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const int M = 1e9 + 7;

int main()
{
    long long  n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    long long x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        x += pow(k, __gcd(i,n));
    }

    cout << (int)(((double)1/n) * x) % M;
    return 0;
}
```

I paste my code to program with test cases but my solution passed half of test cases. I can't find my mistake and I see only one test case. 
First test case is `n = 5` and `k = 2`, and answer is `8`.
Where I could make a mistake?

Comment: Check your loop conditions. Doesn’t match the one in the formula.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but nothing changed :(

Comment: `++i` doesn't do what you think it does. Specifically, for loop conditions are always evaluated initializer then terminator then incrementer. Therefore it doesn't matter if you write `++i` or `i++` in for loops. But since `++i` may mislead people into thinking that the loop is doing something else it is always advisable to use `i++` as a self-documenting reminder of what's happening.

Comment: @rel1x I have updated the answer, check it.

Comment: All of the current answers are most likely wrong, because `x` will probably exceed even `long long` after the for loop, even for `n` as small as `63` and `k` as small as `2`. The modulo is there for a reason: you have to compute it at each step.

Comment: @IVlad you were correct :)

I have edited my answer. I think now it it correct.

Comment: @rel1x Finally, here is some code which works properly (in C++): https://ideone.com/u6Klhn

Sorry, I had some issues with `long` and `long long` in C++

Comment: @slebetman Uh, the opposite is true. Always use `++i` in C++ instead of `i++`. The reason is that the latter may sometimes be slower than the former — not for built-in types like `int`, but for custom types. At any rate, their semantics here are identical so I don’t see how one could be confusing …

Comment: @KonradRudolph his point was different. If you check OP's for loop `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`, he  used `++i` thinking that `i` will vary from `1 to n` (which is not true).

Comment: can you post the problem link

Comment: I don't understand. what does "rotating a necklace by an angle" mean? can you give a small example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your formula is incorrect. The correct one can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_necklaces

My implementation of it has just [passed all the tests](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum12/challenges/count-the-necklaces/submissions/code/3431052).

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry, can't help it if your formula is incorrect but this is the correct implementation for your formula**

In your code, the loop variable `i` is different from the formula. You are moving `i=0,...,n-1`, but the formula says `i=1,2,....n`.

**UPDATE:** I think your line `x += pow(k, __gcd(i,n));` is not pretty correct. When `x+pow(k, __gcd(i,n))` is going to be greater than 10^9 +7, you should take modulo but you are not doing that.

Just to make the code clear, `Modulo` operations is distributive over `+`, So you can write

```
    ( a + b ) % c = ( ( a % c ) + ( b % c ) ) % c
```

But `Modulo` is not distributive over `/`, so you can not just write

```
   ( a / b ) % c = ( ( a % c ) / ( b % c ) ) % c
```

To compute `(x/y)%M` you have to compute

```
    (x * MMI(y)) % M
```

Thank you for @ivlad for pointing out MMI flaw :)

change

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x += pow(k, __gcd(i,n));
 }
 cout << (int)(((double)1/n) * x) % M;
```

to (This is a complete answer)

```
  long long gcd(long a, long b) {
     return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
  }


  long long power(long a, long b, long MOD) {
    long long x = 1, y = a;
    while(b > 0) {
        if(b%2 == 1) {
            x=(x*y);
            if(x>MOD) x%=MOD;
        }
        y = (y*y);
        if(y>MOD) y%=MOD;
        b /= 2;
    }
    return x;
  }

  long long modInverse(long n, long m) {
    return power(n, m - 2, m);
  }

  int main()
  {
    long  n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    for (long i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
        long long power = pow(k, gcd(i,n));
        x = ((x % M) + (power % M)) %M;
    }
    long long mmi =  modInverse(n,M);
    mmi = (x*mmi)%M;
    cout << mmi;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I fix it in my code, but nothing changed! Solution passed half of test cases again.

Comment: Oh, I've got an error  `file.cc:18:49: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('typename enable_if<is_arithmetic<int>::value && is_arithmetic<int>::value, typename __promote<int, int>::type>::type'
      (aka 'double') and 'double')
        x = ((x % M) + (pow(k, __gcd(i,n) % M)) % M;`. I removed last `%M` here, but passed half of test cases.

Comment: This is wrong: you cannot divide by `n` after taking the modulo and then take the modulo again. It will give the wrong answer.

Comment: @IVlad I din't get you

Comment: You computed `x` modulo `M`. Then you divided that result by `n`. That is wrong.

Comment: @IVlad ah I see, I will have to compute modulo multiplicative inverse like in ncr. I am editing the answer

Comment: @IVlad edited :)

rel1x you can try this updated solution.

Comment: It seems @IVlad was talking about something else.

Comment: @karthik I've got  wrong answer from `5` and `2`, but expected answer is `8`. https://ideone.com/zH2d6i

Comment: This is the right idea (did not check the implementation). It might be possible to simplify the formula further (if `n` is so large that even `O(n)` is too much), but I don't see how to do that so far.

Comment: @rel1x I am bit rusty with C++(basically a java developer). May be I am missing a small detail about conversion in C++ or something. You can see that the same code works fine in java - https://ideone.com/lTLWXu

Comment: @karthik sorry, but answers from implementation in java the same with these answers https://www.jasondavies.com/necklaces/?

Comment: @rel1x sorry, i guess it's my mistake in java for pow and gcd functions I used `long`, but in the answer here I used `int`. I think that's the catch. will edit it accordingly. And yes it gives 8 for `n=5,k=2` and 24 for `n=4,k=3`

Comment: you are still getting wrong answer? Can you tell me the test case?

Comment: change everything to long long in power function. 10^9 * 10^9 can overflow

Comment: @ShubhamSharma already they are `long long`. Which values are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I see two things wrong with your program. The first is that `pow` will overflow even for small values of `k` and `n`. Depending on the size of the inputs (which you don't give), `pow` could overflow even before you take the modulus. You should replace `pow` with your own `powModM` which takes `% M` more frequently. Something like

```
int powModM(int k, int n, int M) {
  int res = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    res = (res * k) % M;
  }
  return res;
}
```

although if the exponents are large you might want to replace that with a procedure using `O(log n)` fast exponentiation.

The second, bigger problem is when you divide by `n`. Unlike addition, subtraction, and multiplication, division in modular arithmetic cannot be accomplished by performing the division in ordinary arithmetic then taking the modulus. For one thing, if `gcd(n,10^9+7) != 1`, you could be dividing by 0. (However, since 10^9+7 is prime, that's highly unlikely and I would ignore the issue). The other, more likely issue, is that to divide by `n` in modular arithmetic, you must instead multiply by the inverse of `n`, which is completely different from `1/n`.

Here's a Java routine to calculate the multiplicative inverse using the extended Euclidean algorithm. You can easily adapt it to C++. Note that the quotient `q` in the function is calculated by integer division.

```
public static long inverse(long a, long m) { // mult. inverse of a mod m
    long r = m;
    long nr = a;
    long t = 0;
    long nt = 1;
    long tmp;
    while (nr != 0) {
      long q = r/nr;
      tmp = nt; nt = t - q*nt; t = tmp;
      tmp = nr; nr = r - q*nr; r = tmp;
    }
    if (r > 1) return -1; // no inverse
    if (t < 0) t += m;
    return t;
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand about inverse. What are arguments `a` and `m`?

Comment: `a` is your `n` and `m` is your `M`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about number limits.

`long long` can be `unsigned long long` or even `long double`.

`double` can be `long double`. This in fact is platform-dependent, but may be the reason.

By the way, `n` is delcared as `long long`, can it really be that too large?? If yes, your loop will take very long time and you will probably get "Time Limit Exceeded". If no, simply declare it `int`. Declaring it `long long` while `int` is enough can cause some errors!!

Comment: Even if `n` is small, the exponentiation will cause the entire thing to overflow.